# Does the font displayed in the web mail client come from the provider or our OS?

Tags: windows, macos, fonts, html-email

I understand that some fonts are not provided by the email client and the next available one in the stack/default one will be used instead if this is the case.

However, my question is that does this font actually require the device displaying this email to have that font? For example, imagine the font in the email is Arial, can I still see the email in a browser if my computer does not have Arial installed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have Arial installed, you can't see it in either an email or a browser because they're pulling fonts from the same system.

As you say, [non-system fonts not supported in all email clients](https://www.campaignmonitor.com/dev-resources/will-it-work/webfonts/), and the email clients that don't use system fonts instead. These clients require that a font installed locally to display it in an email. Same thing goes for web browsers.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I am just a bit confused about the second part of your answer. Do you mind clarifying it a bit? Also, the link you attahced says 'However, web font support depends on the email client and how the web font is embedded in the email.', which seems suggesting the font comes from the mail client?

Comment: Web fonts are only accepted by a limited number of email clients, which allow you to view fonts you do not have locally stored.  This is how most web pages are able to get away with using fancy fonts.  The issue is that as I said the majority of email clients do not accept web fonts, so you need to have a stack of 'web-safe' fonts (aka fonts the vast majority of people will have as they come by default in most OS) to ensure it doesn't default to the system default font

Comment: @xcoder Sorry for the confusion, the second part explains how email clients deal with custom web fonts that are included in the font stack. Possibly irrelevant to your problem, but relevant to typography in email in general.

Fonts don't come from the email or the browser, fonts come from the operating system. Non-system fonts can be _specified_ by an email or browser, but an email or browser might not be able to display them and instead fall back on a local system font.